# Try-Except issue with lists in Python

Tags: python, list, try-catch

I have been trying to use word2vec in Python using gensim. While I am using try/except in order to check for words that are not in Google's model and I have encountered with a problem. Every time there is an exception I am able to print the word but there the model stops and does not computer the remaining words that are in the list.

After the code I have displayed the contents of vocabulary list and the model stops in the word travellers without transforming the rest of the words after the word travellers. I am really stuck and I could use some help on this one. Any ideas?

```
for x in range(0,len(data)):
    titles.append(data[x]['title'])
    paragraphs.append(data[x]['paragraphs'])

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('/tmp/models/google2')
for y in range(95,96):
    vocabulary.append(titles[y])
    vocabulary.append(paragraphs[y][0])
    vocabulary.append(paragraphs[y+1][0])
    print vocabulary
    for entry in vocabulary:
        try:
            row = tokenizer.tokenize(entry)
            row = [word for word in row if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
            row = [model[item] for item in row]
            row = [np.sum(item) for item in row]
            last.append(row)
        except KeyError,e:
            print "There is a word that does not exist in the vocabulary: ", e
```

There is a word that does not exist in the vocabulary:  u'travellers'

vocabulary[0]: Asia's global travel boom

vocabulary[1]: Continental shifts are being made in terms of travel, tourism and spending power as more Asian, and especially Chinese, travellers are venturing abroad.

vocabulary[2]: It was the most exciting thing to happen to Central Asia's poorest country in recent memory.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `for y in range(95,96):` the loop only runs once

Comment: It is for testing purposes mate. The loop runs once and loads 3 values into the vocabulary list. There is no need to run more than once in order to produce the desised result. For instance the 2nd loop runs 3 times, as there are 3 values in the vocabulary list. Even if you are correct and that is the issue the calculations should stop before the word travellers and not exactly there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a condition. Like this:

```
for x in range(0,len(data)):
    titles.append(data[x]['title'])
    paragraphs.append(data[x]['paragraphs'])

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('/tmp/models/google2')
for y in range(95,96):
    vocabulary.append(titles[y])
    vocabulary.append(paragraphs[y][0])
    vocabulary.append(paragraphs[y+1][0])
    print vocabulary
    for entry in vocabulary:
        try:
            row = tokenizer.tokenize(entry)
            row = [word for word in row if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
            # in your code, row will be overwritten several times, so I use new variables here
            temp = []
            temp1 = []
            for item in row:
                try:
                    model[item]
                except KeyError, e:
                    continue

                temp.append(model[item])
                temp1.append(np.sum(item))
                last.append(temp1)
        except KeyError,e:
            print "There is a word that does not exist in the vocabulary: ", e
```

Hope it works.

Comment: That is a good way to do it yeah but still I got :
AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: There is an error when you do temp1.append(np.sum(item)) as item is not numeric.I did:
                for item in row:
                try:
                 print item
                 res = np.sum(model[item])
                 print res
                 temp.append(res)
                except KeyError, e:
                    continue
My last issue is that I need to append correctly in order to have the sums of each word's array's be in the the array where they came from. e.g for the sentence [Asia, global, travel, boom] to have sth like [-1.2136844, -1.4799396, -0.75583267, -1.0718837]

Comment: Sorry for the bad format of the code in my last comment. Hope you got what I mean.

Comment: @Swan87 OK. What's the type of item? How to change 'Asia' to 1.2136844? Is there a relation list or something like that?

Comment: No, model[item] does that.I need to do 2 sums. The first sum is the np.sum(model[item]) where I sum up all the values of the vector. What I need is to have those values separately for each vocab entry. What I need is to have 3 arrays in the temp list,like [[-1.2136844, -1.4799396, -0.75583267, -1.0718837],[-0.5,...],[-1.7,...]] and then add each element to get sth like [[0,5],[0,3],[1,7]] and be able to say that the first paragraph is more similar to the title as this sum is closer to title's sum. I need to maintain the arrays as they were created during the vocab.append stage.